# How to use group-by on timestamps correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, data-analysis

I have a timeseries data for a full year for every minute.

```
timestamp               day hour min rainfall_rate           
2010-01-01 00:00:00     1   0   0       x
2010-01-01 00:01:00     1   0   1       x
2010-01-01 00:02:00     1   0   2       x
2010-01-01 00:03:00     1   0   3       x
2010-01-01 00:04:00     1   0   4       x
...                            ...
2010-12-31 23:55:00     365 23  55  
2010-12-31 23:56:00     365 23  56  
2010-12-31 23:57:00     365 23  57  
2010-12-31 23:58:00     365 23  58  
2010-12-31 23:59:00     365 23  59
```

I want to combine the timestamps such that I can get the combined `rainfall_rate` for every month, i.e I want to use `group-by` to combine them based on the date and also the plot them with the axis as timestamp for further analysis.
How can I perform this using pandas?

I used -

`daily_groups = rainfall_df.groupby(rainfall_df.index.date)` then

`daily_groups.get_group(pd.Timestamp(2010,1,1))['rainfall_rate'].sum()` but of course I could not plot them because they are of different shape.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Grouper` with `freq="M"`:

```
print (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))["rainfall_rate"].count())


#
    timestamp
2010-01-31    5
2010-02-28    0
2010-03-31    0
2010-04-30    0
2010-05-31    0
2010-06-30    0
2010-07-31    0
2010-08-31    0
2010-09-30    0
2010-10-31    0
2010-11-30    0
2010-12-31    0
```

Comment: You can also convert the column timestamp to the column which contains months only. But the solution @Henry Yik looks great.
` rainfall_df['month_year'] = rainfall_df['timestamp '].dt.to_period('M') '

Comment: OP wants to get the total count of rainfall for each month instead of assigning a new column.

Comment: sure, then groupby is needed.

Comment: Can you please explain the code, I am a beginner? @HenryYik

Comment: @random_user There is nothing special - your index is already `datetime` so you can group them by month using `pd.Grouper` and then count the number of `rainfall_rate` per group.

Comment: I just ran the code but the `rate` seems to be very large.

Comment: Also why used `count()`? rather than sum?

Comment: I don’t know how exactly your rate is - you can use sum if it suits you.

Comment: I used `sum()`. rate is an integer value. I need the rate for every month.@HenryYik